# Delete corrupt user.config instead of System.ConfigurationErrorException

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm using an `user.config` to store my application settings. I can access the settings in C# for example with `Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1` and the `user.config` file looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Setting1" serializeAs="String">
                <value>ABCDEF</value>
            </setting>
        </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

But when my `user.config` is corrupt for what reason ever, my application is crashing with the following `System.ConfigurationErrorException`.

I would prefer in that case that the application is deleting the corrupt `user.config` file and starts with the default settings.

Is there a way to achieve that?

**Update**

I've seen that this question has been asked before see [user.config corruption issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272830/user-config-corruption-issue) and [User.config corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708868/user-config-corruption).

But If I try the following code

```
// Check for corrupt settings
try
{
    var dummy = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;
}
catch (ConfigurationErrorsException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Settings are corrupt!");
    File.Delete(exception.Filename); 
}
```

the `exception.Filename` is `null`. And If I use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal)` inside my `try` block the exception is not raised in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

I found that Filename is set on a child innerException
Maybe you must iterate innerException